# MultiTenant Hibernate + Spring boot - How to prevent it from looking up for a connection during server startup

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, multi-tenant

We are using  multi tenant hibernate + Spring boot as described in [Multi-Tenancy in Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html#d5e4817).   We are providing  MultiTenantConnectionProvider and  CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver when creating the entity manager (Refer to sample below).

In our MultiTenantConnectionProvider, The target database for a tenant is not statically configured.  Instead, It dynamically determines the target database details of current tenant by calling another service and then creates datasource for it.

Now , we are facing an issue that  when spring boot server is started,  Hibernate is making a call to MultiTenantConenctionProvider.getAnyConnection() method. At the time of server startup, there is no tenant in the context and hence we do not have any database to create a connection for.  Also, we do not have any dummy database in our setup which we can use during server startup time

1. If we return null,  the server startup fails with a NullPointerException
2. If we override anyConnection() method and  throw an exception (as can be see in the code below), the server just logs the exception and continues with the server startup.

With 2, Things work fine and we are able to make progress.   However, we really want to get rid of this unnecessary exception being logged everytime the spring boot server is restarted.

We are looking for a way to turn off  hibernate behaviour of trying to connect to a db during server startup especially when hibernate's multi-tenant strategy is set.  This behavior is inconsistent for a multi-tenant  software

Is there any way, we can prevent hiberate from trying get a connection (i.e making a call to  MultiTenantConenctionProvider.getAnyConnection())  during server startup ?

Please advise

Following is a sample of our  Spring configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MultiTenantHibernateJpaConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

    @Bean
    public MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider() {
        return new MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver() {
        return new CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl();
    }

    @Value("${jpaconfig.packages-to-scan:#{null}}")
    private String packagesToScan;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider,
                                                                       CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver) {

        Map<String, Object> hibernateProps = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        hibernateProps.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA);
        hibernateProps.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProvider);
        hibernateProps.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, currentTenantIdentifierResolver);

        hibernateProps.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action", "none");
        hibernateProps.put("javax.persistence.query.timeout", "5");
        hibernateProps.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        hibernateProps.putAll(this.jpaProperties.getProperties());

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean result = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        if(packagesToScan != null) {
            //handle multiple packages separated by comma
            result.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScan.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
        }
        result.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        result.setJpaPropertyMap(hibernateProps);

        return result;
    }
```

Following is the MultiTenantConnectionProvider implementation

```
public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl extends AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl()
    {
    }

    @Override
    protected DataSource selectAnyDataSource()
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected DataSource selectDataSource(String tenantIdentifier) {
        //This in turn makes a call to a remote service to fetch current tenant 
        //database details and then creates a datasource for it.
        return DataSourceManager.getDataSource(tenantIdentifier);
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException{
        //Called during server startup. Cannot do any thing  as tenant is not known
        // and there is no default datasource
        throw new SQLException("not implemented in multi-tenant environment");
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException
    {
        //Called during server startup. Cannot do any thing  as tenant is not known
        // and there is no default datasource
        throw new SQLException("not implemented in multi-tenant environment");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only called during startup, why not using a default tenantIdentifier just for the startup ?

**Update:**

So if this is not possible. Why don't you implement the Connection interface with a DummyConnection class and return that one on startup ?

Comment: Thanks. That is a possible option.  However, currently, We do not have a  default database .  The database is available only when the tenant is on boarded.  We are looking for a way to turn off hibernate behaviour of trying to connect to a db during server startup especially when hibernate's multi-tenant strategy is set. This behavior is inconsistent for a multi-tenant software